# How do I create a simple login command-line program using Python classes?

Tags: python, class, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a program that uses a class to create accounts and then allow users to log in to accounts. It is not meant to be secure in any way, just for me to learn. I have a problem where I would like to create a object of the class with the parameters name, username, and password. I would like the objects name to be the username that is entered by the user when it is being defined. The problem I have is when the user tries to log in to the account it says that the string entered by the user has no relation to the class. I am not sure if this is because of the login function or the register function or both.

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name, username, password):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.loggedIn = True


def home():
    print("Login, Register")
    a = input("What would you like to do: ")
    if(a == "register" or a == "Register"):
        register()
    elif(a == "Login" or a == "login"):
        login()
    else:
        print("Choose a valid option")
        home()
def register():
    n = input("Name: ")
    u = input("Username: ")
    p = input("Password: ")
    u = User(n, u, p)
    print("Welcome, " + u.name)
    home()
def login():
    l = input("Username: ")
    l2 = input("Password")
    if(l2 == l.password):
        print("Welcome, " + l.name)
    else:
        print("Incorrect username or password")
        login()
    home()

home()
```

Comment: _The problem I have is when the user tries to log in to the account it says that the string entered by the user has no relation to the class._ Can you clarify what that means?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something that will work for you for one go. But I think that because we are creating u = User(n, u, p) in the register function it is a local variable and so when the function gets called again it will replace "u" with a new instance of the class and the old one is erased for lack of better words. So in other words, the class isn't being really being utilized properly. I could be wrong about this though. I know this isn't the best answer but I hope it helps with troubleshooting. (im still learning about classes myself)

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name, username, password):
        self.name = name
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.loggedIn = True


def home(user):
    print("Login, Register")
    a = input("What would you like to do: ")
    if(a == "register" or a == "Register"):
        register()
    elif(a == "Login" or a == "login"):
        login(user)
    else:
        print("Choose a valid option")
        home('')

def register():
    n = input("Name: ")
    u = input("Username: ")
    p = input("Password: ")
    u = User(n, u, p)
    print("Welcome, " + u.name)
    home(u)


def login(user):
    l = input("Username: ")
    l2 = input("Password")
    if(l2 == user.password):
        print("Welcome, " + user.name)
    else:
        print("Incorrect username or password")
        login(user)
    home('')

home('')
```

Comment: I was trying to use this project to learn classes, but I think i bit off a bit more than I could chew. I will come back to this once i've learned a bit more.

Comment: Here is a small project that helped me understand classes a little better. I hope this helps! https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-create-bankaccount-class-with-deposit-withdraw-function/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer that shows how to do this using a class.

```
class login:
    def __init__(self):
        self.credintials = {}
    def register(self, username, password):
        self.credintials[username] = password

    def check(self, user, pas):
        print(self.credintials )
        if user in self.credintials.keys() and pas == self.credintials[user] :
            print("Login success!")
        else:
            print('Wrong Username or Password')

s = login()

Stop = False

while Stop == False:
    tasks = (input('What would you like to do? enter [Register], [Login], or [quit]'))
    # Calling functions with that class object
    if tasks == 'Register':
        Name = (input('Please enter username'))
        Pword= (input('Please enter password'))
        s.register(Name, Pword)

    if tasks == 'Login':
        LoginInfoUser = (input('Please enter Username'))
        LoginInfoPassword = (input('Please enter Password'))
        s.check(LoginInfoUser,LoginInfoPassword)
    if tasks == 'quit':
        print("See you later!")
        Stop =True
```